# Why I cant retrieve the facebook gender? [Laravel 5.1 Socialite]

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I just made an auth controller with Laravel Socialite. First time I just retrieve the name and email data, and then I try to to retrieve the gender but it comes with an error that says

> Undefined property: Laravel\Socialite\Two\User::$gender

Someone please help me to solve my problem, oh yeah my web still in development mode but I think it's not a problem because in facebook developer documentation said I still have access to basic information like first name, last name, profile picture, gender and age range.

Controller Source Code:

```php
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}


public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    try {
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return Redirect::to('login/facebook');
    }

    $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user);

    Auth::login($authUser, true);

    return Redirect::to('home');
}


private function findOrCreateUser($fbUser)
{
    if ($authUser = User::where('email', $fbUser->email)->first()) {
        return $authUser;
    }
    $role = "member";
    return User::create([
        'firstname' => $fbUser->name,
        'email' => $fbUser->email,
        'gender' => $fbUser->gender,
        'role' => $role
    ]);
}
```

Here I provide what i've got if i use `dd($user);` method :

```
User {# ▼
  +token: "tokken value"
  +id: "id value"
  +nickname: null
  +name: "name value"
  +email: "email value"
  +avatar: "avatar value"
  +"user": array:value [▶]
  +"avatar_original": "avatar_original value"
}
```

Comment: can you do $user = Socialite::driver('facebook'); dd($user); to see what is being returned and also confirm `gender` exists

Comment: I just did it and it doesnt callback the gender value, what should i do?

Comment: please may I see what is being returned ? I am having issue with facebook authentication on my localhost, hence I don't know what the response looks like

Comment: I just edited my post that's what i've got if use dd($user); method, facebook login api parse facebook profile value but it doesn't parse gender value. Hope it can help your problem

Comment: Good. What's inside here +"user" array...click the arrow to check please. Can you see gender there if yes. Then you can try using array keys

Comment: Wow its work thanks sir hehe..

Comment: Good. Is this what you used.. `$user['user']['gender']` or `$user->user['gender']`

Answer (score 0):

```
'gender' => $fbUser->user['gender'],
```

Because gender comes in user[] array... so you access to it that way.

But remember you'll need to get the Facebook permission for your app to retrieve this value.